# How to call Express function from another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have these express functions:

```
const token = require("./auth").genToken;
const rp = require("request-promise");
const url = "https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/";

module.exports = {
  async listInvoices(req, res) {
    let response;
    try {
      const full_url = url + "invoices";
      const auth = await token();

      response = await rp({
        url: full_url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: auth,
        json: true
      });

      return res.json(response);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error });
    }
  },

  async listBankTransactions(req, res) {
    let response;
    try {
      const full_url = url + "banktransactions";
      const auth = await token();

      response = await rp({
        url: full_url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: auth,
        qs: req.body,
        json: true
      });

      return res.json(response);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error });
    }
  },

  async matchTransactions(req, res) {
    let transactions = await module.exports.listBankTransactions(req, res);
    let invoices = await module.exports.listInvoices(req, res);
  }
};
```

They have different routes, and I can call them. However, I want the `matchTransactions` function to call `listInvoices` and `listBankTransactions` and store their responses in variables, so I can manipulate these data and then return the `matchTransactions` response.

The way my code is right now, `listBankTransactions` returns the response instead of storing in `transactions` constant, and then there is an exception on the `listInvoices` response, because the response was already returned by `listBankTransactions`.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem recently and didn't find any solution that you're probably thinking of. ;) The way I handled it was to outsource the repeated code of the functions to external functions that are not middleware and make them return promises/resolved promises. Maybe it will help you. I found the then-catch notation much better for this.

```
const middlewareA = (req, res, next) => {
    ascyncCodeOfMiddlewareA
    .then(externalLogicFunction)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
}

const middlewareB = (req, res, next) => {
    externalLogicFunction()
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
}

const externalLogicFunction = () => {
    ...
    return Promise.resolve(something);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, this was my first thought, however I thought it should have a better way. If nobody comes with a better solution, I'll apply this one. Thanks!